# How do I import an object from a client component into a server component, in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js 13 app (using the app router) with a server component and a client component.

I am trying to import a plain JS object that I defined in the client component, into the server component:

```
// ClientComponent.js
'use client';

export const exportedObject = { foo: bar };

export default ClientComponent = () => { return <div>RCC</div> };
```

And:

```
// ServerComponent.js
import { exportedObject } from './ClientComponent';

// This log tells me the object is a function
console.log(exportedObject);

export default ServerComponent = () => {
  // Trying to access exportedObject does not work, I get the same result as above
  // (i.e. it is a function that will throw an error if run)
  console.log(exportedObject);

  return (<div>RSC</div>);
}
```

The `exportedObject` becomes a function for some reason, when importing it into the server component.

Why is that and how could I fix it without turning `ServeComponent` into a client component?

Comment: Have you tried moving the `exportedObject` to a different directory? Like `utils/utils.js`

Comment: I was able to solve it by extracting the object into its own file, without `use client`, as suggested by @kinduser. I still do not understand why the OP code does not work though.